# Assembly code of malloc

Tags: debugging, malloc

I want to view the assembly code of `malloc()`, `calloc()` and `free()` but when I print the assembly code on radare2 it gives me the following code:

```
push rbp                 
mov rbp, rsp
sub rsp, 0x10
mov eax, 0xc8            
mov edi, eax             
call sym.imp.malloc      
xor ecx, ecx
mov qword [local_8h], rax
mov eax, ecx
add rsp, 0x10
pop rbp
ret
```

How can I see `sym.imp.malloc` function code? Is there any way to see the code or any website to see the assembly?

Comment: If you believe that my answer answers your question please consider upvote and accept it :-)

Answer (score 1):

Since libc is an open-source library, it is freely available and you can simply read the source code.
The source-code of malloc is available on many places online ([example](https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/malloc/malloc.c.html)), and you can view the source of different versions of libc under `malloc/malloc.c` [here](https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/glibc/).

The symbol `sym.imp.malloc` is how radare flags the address of `malloc` in the PLT (Procedure Linkage Table) and not the function itself.

**Reading the Assembly of the function can be done in several ways:**

Open your local libc library with radare2, seek to malloc, analyze the function and then print its disassmbly:

```
$ r2 /usr/lib/libc.so.6
[0x00020630]> s sym.malloc
[0x0007c620]> af
[0x0007c620]> pdf
```

If you want to see `malloc` when linked to another binary you need to open the binary in `debug mode`, then step to `main` to make it load the library, then search for the address of `malloc`, seek to it, analyze the function and print the disassembly:

```
$ r2 -d /bin/ls
Process with PID 20540 started...
= attach 20540 20540
bin.baddr 0x00400000
Using 0x400000
Assuming filepath /bin/ls
asm.bits 64
[0x7fa764841d80]> dcu main
Continue until 0x004028b0 using 1 bpsize
hit breakpoint at: 4028b0
[0x004028b0]> dmi libc malloc~name=malloc$
vaddr=0x7fa764315620 paddr=0x0007c620 ord=4162 fwd=NONE sz=388 bind=LOCAL type=FUNC name=malloc
vaddr=0x7fa764315620 paddr=0x0007c620 ord=5225 fwd=NONE sz=388 bind=LOCAL type=FUNC name=malloc
vaddr=0x7fa764315620 paddr=0x0007c620 ord=5750 fwd=NONE sz=388 bind=GLOBAL type=FUNC name=malloc
vaddr=0x7fa764315620 paddr=0x0007c620 ord=7013 fwd=NONE sz=388 bind=GLOBAL type=FUNC name=malloc
[0x004028b0]> s 0x7fa764315620
[0x7fa764315620]> af
[0x7fa764315620]> pdf
```